# Change class by searching for the closest class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change the class of my closest div after pressing a button. Let me make it more clear by showing some code. I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="title">
        <div class="aa">-</div>
            <div class="ab">-</div>
            <div class="ac">-</div>
            <div class="navigation">                                
                    <a href="#" class="test">Test link</a>
            </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content not_active">
    <p>
    Text
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

With the following CSS:

```
.active{
  display:block;
}
.not_active{
  display:none;
}
```

Now my goal is to find the closest div that has the class: `.not_active` and change that class after pressing on the hyperlink with class: `navigation`.

I tried it with jQuery with the following code:

```
$(function () {
  $('.navigatie a').click(function () {             
    $(this).parent().parent().find('.not_active').toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

but with no succes. What I am doing wrong?

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/cuzfjxc8/)

Comment: what is `navigatie` ?

Comment: You don't have any elements with the class `navigatie`

Comment: you have a typo.. should be `navigation` instead of `navigate`

Comment: Use  `$(this).closest('.wrapper').find('.not_active').toggleClass('active'); ` instead

Answer (score 2):

It is because you are using `.navigatie` class instead of `.navigation`.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/cuzfjxc8/1/) the `JSFiddle`.

Comment: Oh really. Damn xd haha. But still would writing it down like that be the optimal way? Is there not a better way of writing this down instead of using parent() etc?